# Error in Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have configured Marketing cloud connect and it is working fine.

I created an Apex Trigger for contact object and trigger send was working fine before 2 days.

But now when I try to create a new Triggered send it is throwing the error on click of Activate Button.

> Activation Failed. Please contact your system administrator.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Activation Failed. Please contact your system administrator.]

Comment: What does the debug log show?  This is just the error shown to the user.

Comment: @KoenCertyn....there is no error shows in debug log. The screenshot which i attached is the windows pop up error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Atheri thanks for your comment.
I also did try initiate log and performed the same activity but, there is no error or exception has been captured.

Actually, i haven't update my Profile center in my email template.
This is causing an issue.

After an updating the profile center in the template ....the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Marketing Cloud tab in Salesforce, click on *Configure Marketing Cloud Connector* and click on *Initiate Logging* and then try again.

In case there isn't anything noted in the debug logs, try deleting this trigger and re-creating / activating it from scratch while logging is active.